# Laravel Lumen Use Extended Eloquent models as default

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, lumen

I have extended my Eloquent models with my custom methods.

The Eloquent models are in: `App\Database\Model`

The Extended Eloquent models are in: `App\Models`

I've got a file `App\Models\File`

```php
    namespace App\Models;

    use App\Database\Model\File as BaseFile;

    class File extends BaseFile
    {
        public function mySpecialMethod()
        {
            // Code
        }
    }
```

But when I get the file like this:

```
// use App\Models\Folder

$folder = Folder::select('folder.*')->first();

$file = $folder->file;

echo $file->mySpecialMethod();
```

I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mySpecialMethod()
```

Which I understand because `$folder->file` relates to `App\Database\Model\File` instead of `App\Models\File`

How can I make Eloquent use my Extended models?

Comment: What is the relation between folder and file ?

Comment: There is a one to many relation between folder and file

Comment: Can you check if FIle model extended from your created Eloquent?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I don't know exactly what you mean, but I can use the mySpecialMethod() when creating a seperate query on file itself via my Extended model. When I chain to the file I get the Eloquent model directly instead of the Extended model.